# Зачем в Jquery используются аргументы в IIFE

Tags: jquery, javascript

Изучая исходники Jquery сталкнулся с вопросом зачем здесь аргументы( window, undefined) в

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    })(window);
```

Подскажите зачем они нужны?

Comment: Вот, нашел [похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined).

Comment: @Deonis: там и ответ есть :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямо сейчас в хроме мне не удаётся воспроизвести те проблемы от которых защищает этот трюк, возможно этим страдают лишь некоторые движки.

Дело в том, что в JavaScript `undefined` -- корректное имя переменной, и его можно переопределить. Если в вызове функции есть пропущенные аргументы, то соответствующие им параметры принимают значение `undefined`. Таким трюком переменной `undefined` возвращается изначальное значение, даже если какой-то умник его переопределил.

`window` передаётся чтобы запомнить ссылку на объект window, и если кто-то ниже сделает что-то вроде `window = 1`, то window внутри функции будет по-прежнему указывать на старый `window`.

Answer (score 4):

> window передаётся чтобы запомнить ссылку на объект window, и если кто-то ниже сделает что-то вроде window = 1, то window внутри функции будет по-прежнему указывать на старый window.

**совсем нет**, всё сделано для уменьшения размера js файла, т.к. допустим в функции `window` и `undefined` используются более 9000 раз, то минификаторы заменят их имена на `a` и `b`

```
(function(a, b) {
     ...
})(window);
```

что существенно уменьшит размер библиотеки или фреймворка

Comment: о, клёво. Я про это как-то не подумал.

Comment: @Spectre как всегда даёт мне чему учиться... +1